# SQL Sub-Join Syntax

Tags: sql, join, scope, alias

When using a sub join, I have noticed two different ways of producing the same results.  Within the sub-join, one uses a 'select' to join two tables and then gives it an alias that is referenced on subsequent lines.  The other just joins two tables 'anonymously' and the subsequent lines use the Sub-Join's table alias names.  I have example code below.  My questions are:

1. Are these equivalent and one just saves keystrokes?
2. Does the one using 'select' create a temporary table whereas the other doesn't?
3. Will there be any performance differences between the two?  I don't think there will be based on the execution analyzer but I thought I would ask.
4. Is there a 'name' for one or the others 'sub-join style' (e.g. aliased sub-join vs. anonymous sub join?)
5. As far as the scoping rules of aliasing of table and column names go, are there any good documents that someone could point me to which might explain situations like these?  I have searched and can't find anything that matches (although I'm not sure I'm searching 'correctly')?

Here are the two queries:

```
SELECT bp1.*, b1.* 
from Bugs b1 
JOIN BugsProducts bp1 ON b1.bug_id = bp1.bug_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select b2.*, bp2.product_id 
                from Bugs b2 
                JOIN BugsProducts bp2 ON b2.bug_id = bp2.bug_id) AS sub1
ON (bp1.product_id = sub1.product_id AND (b1.date_reported < sub1.date_reported))
WHERE sub1.bug_id IS NULL;

SELECT bp1.*, b1.* 
from Bugs b1 
JOIN BugsProducts bp1 ON b1.bug_id = bp1.bug_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Bugs b2 JOIN BugsProducts bp2 ON b2.bug_id = bp2.bug_id)
ON (bp1.product_id = bp2.product_id AND (b1.date_reported < b2.date_reported))
WHERE b2.bug_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

I researched this topic further and have found the answers I was looking for. I hope this helps someone else in the future.

When performing a JOIN on a 'subquery', as in the first case, you must provide an Alias for the subquery and therefore must use that Alias when referring to the data from that subquery. JOIN-ing on a subquery gives you more detailed control over what fields will be returned and how they are formatted, etc. so this may be preferable in some cases when you need to 'customize' the data. The data returned from a subquery like this may be called a 'virtual table' or 'derived table' among others.

The second case in my example is just a 'Mutli-Join'. There is nothing special about it per se. It involves less typing and may be preferable when customizing the return fields is not needed.

Both queries produce identical execution paths in my environment. YMMV.

Here is a good article which explains subqueries and joins (among other subquery topics) for a more complete description:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/subqueries-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use this? :

```
SELECT bp1.*, b1.* 
FROM bugs b1, bugsproducts bp1 
WHERE b1.bug_id = bp1.bug_id AND b1.bug_is IS NULL
```

As alias seems easier to me and much cleaner and shorter code

and what should

```
(b1.date_reported < b2.date_reported)
```

return, isnt b1 = Bugs and b2 = Bugs, thus the same table

Comment: Thanks John but my question isn't how to make the query work.  The question is basically 'what is the difference between the two queries?'  I'm trying to understand why one style of query is better than the other (if it is at all).